# How do you call an action, without using a route, from within the view?

Tags: php, controller, dispatcher, phalcon

router

`new Router(false);`

view

`module/views/index/index.volt`

route

```
$router->add("/", array(
        'module'     => 'module',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index',
));
```

How would you call an action named "otherAction" set in the index controller from the index.volt using a button or an anchor without adding a new route?

```
<?php

namespace Multiple\Module\Controllers;

class IndexController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function otherAction()
    {

    } 
}
```

In short Id like to dispatch directly from the view itself.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

I think your commentor is correct, you can't do this in a phalcon view.  I have seen Laravel blade extensions that do exactly what you are asking by using the syntax {{ controller@method }} but I am not aware of any such thing for phalcon.

Best I can suggest is this:

```
<?php

namespace Multiple\Module\Controllers;

class IndexController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $other_data = $this->otherAction();
        // ... extract the required data from $other_data
        // ... pass the required data to the view
    }

    public function otherAction()
    {

    } 
}
```

I was originally suggesting that you would not call that function from the view, however it is possible by passing the controller to the view as a view variable. I'm unconvinced that it's the best idea but here is how you would do it:

```
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->controller = $this;
    }
```

Inside the view you would then do something like this:

```
<?php $result = $controller->otherAction(); ?>
```

... then you would need to interpret the value $result and act accordingly (depending on how you code otherAction() and what it returns).

Once again I don't think this is a good idea. Coding PHP inside templates breaks the view / controller separation a little bit, it would be better code to gather all of the variables in your controller and pass the to the view rather than expect to have the view call back to the controller to fetch things.

Comment: How would you call that function set on $this from the view?

Comment: By *call* I meant using an anchor or a button.

Comment: Without a route? You can't. Add a route to map the button URL to a function, that's what routes are for.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to hide some actions and fire them dependant on parameters collected/sent on query, you are not necesarry to `false` Router.

In one of my controllers i have a production-working solution like this:

**Initialization**

```
public function initialize()
{
    // if someone tries to get to subaction of controller, prevent it.
    if ($this->dispatcher->getActionName() != 'index') {
        $this->dispatcher->setActionName('index');
    }

    // exploding request path - should you implement Path class.
    if ($path = Path::get()) {
        $this->hash = $path[1]; // or 2 or whatever you need
    } else {
        $this->dispatcher->forward(['controller' => 'notfound404']);
    }
}
```

This way all over the controller i do have a `hash` property, having a parameter I can `case` over.

**Example indexAction**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
        // not a POST request, using mainAction to generate view.
        $this->dispatcher->forward(['action' => 'main']);
    } else {
        switch ($this->hash) {
            case 'stepOne':
            case 'stepTwo':
            case 'summary':
                $this->dispatcher->forward(['action' => $this->hash]);
                break;
            default:
                $this->dispatcher->forward(['action' => 'error']);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Probably will not work with Router turned off anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not detailed enough.

did you try :

`<a href="index/other">Click to call otherAction</a>`

in your index.volt view?

Comment: Did you use Phalcon before? There are plenty of information. For example  you can tell from the false flag that what you are proposing wouldn't work unless I had a route for it.